# Return the result of a mocked method to another mocked method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've got a class that has the following implementation:

```
public sealed class HotelRepository : IHotelRepository
{
    private readonly string _dataSource;

    public HotelRepository(string dataSource) => _dataSource = dataSource;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Hotel>> GetAllAsync() =>
        await Task.Run(() => JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(_dataSource))["hotels"].ToList().Select(x => x.ToObject<Hotel>()));

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Hotel>> GetListByMatchAsync(string name) =>
        await GetAllAsync().ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Where(y => y.Name.Contains(name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
}
```

As you can see, the `GetListByMatchAsync` method calls `GetAllAsync`, then does some logic before returning the result.

When I tried to mock this repository for unit testing, I'm struggling to get a result out of `GetListByMatchAsync` as it always fails as a null reference exception.

Here's the unit test:

```
[TestCase("Test", "X")]
[TestCase("Hotel", "X")]
[TestCase("Name", "X")]
public async Task GetListByMatchAsync_GetHotelListByMatchingNameAsync_ReturnsFiveMatchingHotels(string name, string nonMatch)
{

    _hotelRepositoryMock = new Mock<IHotelRepository>();
    _hotelRepository = _hotelRepositoryMock.Object;

    // Set up sample data.
    var data = new List<Hotel>
    {
        new Hotel{Id = 1, Name = $"{name}", Description = "Description2", Location = "Location2", Rating = Rating.Two},
        new Hotel{Id = 2, Name = $"{name.ToUpper()}", Description = "Description1", Location = "Location1", Rating = Rating.Five},
        new Hotel{Id = 3, Name = $"{name.ToLower()}", Description = "Description2", Location = "Location2", Rating = Rating.Three},
        new Hotel{Id = 4, Name = $"{name} {nonMatch}", Description = "Description2", Location = "Location2", Rating = Rating.One},
        new Hotel{Id = 5, Name = nonMatch, Description = "Description2", Location = "Location2", Rating = Rating.One},
    };

    // Set up mock methods and ensure these method returns any sample data.
    _hotelRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetListByMatchAsync(It.IsAny<string>()));
    _hotelRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllAsync()).ReturnsAsync(data);


    var result = await _hotelRepository.GetListByMatchAsync(name);

    // Cast to list to make assertions.
    var hotels = result.ToList();

    Assert.That(hotels, Is.TypeOf<List<Hotel>>());
    Assert.That(hotels.Count, Is.EqualTo(4));
}
```

How can I make this test work such that the `GetListByMatchAsync` mock method does some logic after calling the mocked `GetAllAsync` method?

Comment: If you mock `GetListByMatchAsync` then it won't call anything, it will return what you set it up to return,which in this case is nothing because you didn't code the setup to return anything.

Comment: @Crowcoder ok so i removed the part where I am setting up the `GetListByMatchAsync` method as ran it. Now I get an empty list returned - this is not what what it should return (should be 4 things)

Comment: It is difficult to guess what your code looks like now that you have made a change. Please don't assume it's so simple I will just know. If you are not making a setup for a method that you still want to call you need to set `CallBase = true` on the mock.

Comment: @Azhari It seems a bit strange that you are trying to do. Usually we are using Moq to create moqs for the dependencies of a class and then we try to test the behavior of a concrete object of this class. It does not make any sense to mock a class and then try to test this mock.

Comment: Indeed, what you would want to mock in this test is `File` - which is hard to mock. Testable code would have an abstraction of that `File`-functionality, which would be injected into your repository. Then, by mocking the `File` abstraction, you can unit-test your repository.

Comment: @Christos The only element I am trying to mock in this class is the data set being returned by `GetAllAsync` - everything else I need to work normally in order to test that those methods are working as intended.

Comment: When mock interface use CallBase(). So it will call normal implementations for not mocked methods

Answer (score 2):

First, the code that you have shown cannot possibly work because the methods that you are trying to set up are not virtual. Declare the methods you want to `Setup` as `virtual`.

Second, this is wrong:

> ```
> _hotelRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetListByMatchAsync(It.IsAny<string>()));
> ```

With this call, you're effectively setting up `GetListByMatchAsync` to return `default(Task<IEnumerable<Hotel>>)`, i.e. `null`. That's obviously not what you want. Either:

- use `.Returns(...)` to specify what the method should return; or,
- use `.CallBase()` if the method should simply return whatever the implementation in the base class would return. (This is likely what you need.)